# Welcome to new moderators Michael and James!

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

Due to increasing needs and request for handling the load on Worldbuilding, we've been requested to get new moderators into the site. However, as it's not really been that long since your [last election](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/election/2), February this year, and it is still August this year, we've grabbed the two runner-ups from the previous election to act as your moderators starting today:

[image: Michael Kjörling] [image: James]

They'll be joining the [existing team](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly - please join me in welcoming them and thanking them for volunteering.

As well, we'd like to thank [Serban Tanasa](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/3510/serban-tanasa), who has chosen to step down. Thank you for the hard work you've provided in caring for this site over the past year and a half!

Comment: Thanks Serban for all your hard work, and welcome to Michael and James!

Comment: What Monica said :)

Comment: Uhg, @James, who let *him* in?

Comment: @NexTerren I assure you it was all nepotism.

Comment: Shall we say welcome *back*, Michael? :)

Comment: hello! :) we needed new admins